# How to properly send messages to another screen using SSH?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh

I have an Ubuntu box set up and a Mac from which I am trying to send a message to the Ubuntu screen

Can someone provide a short guide or a series of commands (I know it has to do with "screen") to send a message to the other computer's screen.

I've googled around, but to no avail.

Answer (score 8):

Are you looking for the [`write`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/write) command?

Comment: Probably, or the `wall` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do `echo message > /dev/ttyX` or `echo message > /dev/pts/X`. You will need privileges if it's another user's tty.

And if you want some fancy, use `figlet message > /dev/pts/X` to do things like this:

```
 _ __ ___   ___  ___ ___  __ _  __ _  ___ 
| '_ ` _ \ / _ \/ __/ __|/ _` |/ _` |/ _ \
| | | | | |  __/\__ \__ \ (_| | (_| |  __/
|_| |_| |_|\___||___/___/\__,_|\__, |\___|
                               |___/
```